# save stored function for hibernate in-memory test

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I'm running JUnit EJB test in memory and need to store an SQL function using hibernate, since the test is not calling real database.

Is it possible?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GAMES.get_technical_game_play_start 
(client_id_s IN INTEGER, interval_step IN INTEGER, date_to IN TIMESTAMP, no_older_than IN TIMESTAMP) 
RETURN TIMESTAMP AS
  date_from TIMESTAMP;
  new_date_to TIMESTAMP;
BEGIN
  date_from := date_to - interval_step / (24 * 60);
  SELECT DATE_INSERTED INTO new_date_to FROM GAMES.TRANSACTIONS WHERE TRANSACTIONS.CLIENT_ID = client_id_s 
    AND DATE_INSERTED >= date_from 
    AND DATE_INSERTED < date_to 
    AND DATE_INSERTED >= no_older_than 
    AND ROWNUM<= 1 ORDER BY DATE_INSERTED;
  IF new_date_to IS NULL THEN 
    RETURN date_to; 
  END IF;
  return GAMES.get_technical_game_play_start (client_id_s, interval_step, new_date_to, no_older_than);
end;
```